# Captcha code on posts and reviews

Tags: feature-request, captcha

It is ridiculously easy to make a bot that will spam posts/comments on posts, and auto-review posts, votes and edits (bypassing the 'attention tests'). Almost every kid, who wants to spam random swears, or advertise his Minecraft server, has the ability to do so.

I think, Stack OverFlow needs captcha code verification on certain actions (asking questions, posting answers, reviewing, etc.), even if it will be very clear to see, and fast to type up.

Is there a way I can report that, or suggest it somewhere, where the Stack OverFlow developers will hear this?

Comment: Ask yourself: if it's so easy to write such a bot, why don't we see this all the time? Why is it so hard to find spam and trolling anywhere on the site?

Comment: Now I've a good question for S.O: How can I make a bot to advertise my Minecraft server?

Comment: A minecraft server is just an example, make a simple program that will just go through the # latest questions, and post some specified text as an answer (text to advertize), then after 50 or so of these "spam answers" get banned, EASILY sign up with a new account, and continue doing this until you are bored. (trust me, there are people in this world that would think its a great idea)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is one of the places where you can suggest feature-requests, and the Stack Exchange developers will see your request.

However, the site *already* employs captchas when posting, but most users won't see these, or at least not very often. That's because the developers do an excellent job adjusting *trust*, the confidence that you are actually a human, as you gain reputation on the site. That way those that are actually contributing and have proven to use the site the way it was designed to be used *don't get slowed down all the time*.

And captchas are not the only way to keep automated crap out; most 'robots' are running into rate limits in place for low-reputation accounts, and then there is the automated spam detection and various other defences.

So although it may be ridiculously easy to *make* a bot, getting it to actually advertise on the site is a hell of a lot harder! If it were that easy, Stack Overflow would have drowned in spam a long time ago already. You just don't see how much is blocked entirely automatically *already*:

[image: spam blocked graph]

([*source*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237848/anti-spam-blocking-questions-whose-bodies-end-with-a-raw-hyperlink/237882))

Comment: That is a ridiculous amount of spam. I wonder how many specially trained apes it takes to wade through this *every* day.

Comment: alright then, whatever

Answer (score 5):

I don't mean to come off as a hardass but if I have to negotiate a flippin' CAPTCHA just to post an answer to someone else's inquiry, I'll find another site to offer my volunteered assistance on.

Thankfully the trust algorithms are not quite that strict.

Comment: +1, and adding, we don't need it anyway due to Stack doing a better job than basic devs sticking in a captcha!

Answer (score 2):

If it detects robot-like behavior, [it will prompt you with a CAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/captcha). However, that’s a burden on normal users, so it only does that if it thinks you might be a robot.